# Kubernetes containers fails giving CrashLoopBackOff error

Tags: docker, kubernetes

My kubernetes containers are giving `CrashLoopBackOff` error. When I looked inside using describe command, I got the following error:

> Error: failed to start container "app-mongo": Error response from
>   daemon: linux runtime spec devices: readdirent: invalid argument

The Deployment is below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose-file.yaml
    kompose.version: 1.5.0 (999278f)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: app-mongo
  name: app-mongo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: app-mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: xxx.xx.xx.xx:5000/mongo:0.1
        name: app-mongo
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regsecret
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: I think you should check your `mongo:0.1` image. it seems an issue is only there. I've successfully created your deployment with `mongo` image from Docker Hub.

Comment: @Nickolay Can you please tell me in which environment did you try? I'm trying on ubuntu 16.04.02 version. I've setup k8s via conjure-up option running on a single node.

Answer (score -1):

Please give a try after having the image("app-mongo") on the machine.

Comment: Try elaborating your answer, what does 'this image' refer to ?